# Linq - Loop through list of strings and add results to var variable

Tags: c#, string, list, linq

I have my code sample below.

```cs
List<string> userIds = userAppService.GetUserIds()
    .Where(usr => usr.Status == "Active")
    .Select(u => u.User_Id)
    .ToList();
```

Now i would like loop through list of above UserId's and add the result to var variable.

```cs
foreach(string str in userIds)
{
    var result = SLSDBContext.USER_HISTORY
        .Where(i => i.UserId == str)
        .Select(x => new 
        {
            x.UserId,
            x.LogCount,
            x.IsRegistered 
        });

    return this.Json(result)
}
```

The problem with above is i will not be able to access 'result' variale outside of foreach block.. If i am trying yo declare 'result' variable before foreach block i am not able to assign the type to it.

any better way to get the desired result ?

I tried using Any() operator in Linq but i am not able to get the desired result.

```cs
var result = SLSDBContext.USER_HISTORY
    .Where(i => i.UserId.Contains(userIds))
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        x.UserId,
        x.LogCount,
        x.IsRegistered 
    });
```

Comment: do you want to *append* the result of the current interation on every iteration, or *replace* the previous (because that's what you're currently doing)?

Comment: I'm almost sure you need `Where(i => userIds.Contains(i.UserId))`, not `Where(i => i.UserId.contains(userIds))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `Join`:

```
var activeUsers = userAppService.GetUserIds()
    .Where(usr => usr.Status == "Active");
var result = from uh in SLSDBContext.USER_HISTORY
             join au in activeUsers
                 on uh.UserId equals au.User_Id
             select new {
                 uh.UserId,
                 uh.LogCount,
                 uh.IsRegistered 
             };    

return this.Json(result.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can initialize the `result` before loop and use `Concat` method.

```
var result = Enumerable.Empty<USER_HISTORY>();

foreach(string str in userIds)
{
    result = result.Concat(SLSDBContext.USER_HISTORY.Where(i => i.UserId == str).Select(x => new {
      x.UserId,
      x.LogCount,
      x.IsRegistered 
    }));
}

return this.Json(result);
```